# How to manually add a program to the list of windows optional features so that it can be turned on or off?

Tags: windows, powershell, windows-registry, dism, winpe

The `C:\Windows\System32\OptionalFeatures.exe` program allows to `Turn windows features on or off` by checking or clearing the checkboxes from the shown list.

For educational/learning purposes, how can a custom program (say a simple hello world application - assume we have the executable or the source code available for the application) be added to that list so that it can be turned on and off just like the other Windows Optional Features?

Comment: I am not sure if you can to do this, but you would have to write your own program (indeed, even it this might be possible)

Answer (score 1):

You cannot add custom Windows Optional Features ([Features on Demand](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/features-on-demand-v2--capabilities?view=windows-11)) or Capabilities to windows.

"Features" install at the operating system level - stuff like virtualization support and developer tools. They are closer to windows update packages than applications, as each one is requested/downloaded/installed through the windows update service. Each build of windows only supports a specific list of these Features, and this cannot be changed.

---

The current built-in way to allow custom applications to be turned on and off is through the Microsoft Store on windows, which supports installing pretty much anything now:

- Universal Windows Platform (UWP) apps
- Progressive Web Apps (PWA)
- MSIX content
- Win32-based applications. (`.msi`, `setup.exe`, and other Win32 package/installer types)

Store apps can be Provisioned, where they are not necessarily installed until the user needs it. When uninstalled by the user, they remain provisioned for other users or reinstallation.

Another option is to use the new built-in [Windows Package Manager](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/package-manager/) (winget) to grab your installers from.

There are plenty of other options available for managing that kind of thing too, like publishing software through AD group policy or using Microsoft SCCM / Endpoint manager, etc. Just nothing that adds to the "Optional Features" list